# Updating existing documents in elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch

Is it possible add more fields to existing documents in elasticsearch?

I indexed for instance the following document:

```
{
    "user":"xyz",
    "message":"for increase in fields"
}
```

Now I want to add 1 more field to it i.e date:

```
{
    "user":"xyz",
    "message":"for increase in fields",
    "date":"2013-06-12"
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For Elastic Search Check [update](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/update/)

> The update API also support passing a partial document (since 0.20),
>   which will be merged into the existing document (simple recursive
>   merge, inner merging of objects, replacing core “keys/values” and
>   arrays)

Solr 4.0 also supports partial updates. check [Link](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a [partial update](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html) (assuming the document has an ID of 1):

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/1/_update' -d '
{
    "doc" : {
    "date":"2013-06-12"
    }
}'
```

Then query the document:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?q=user:xyz'
```

You should see something like:

```
"_id":"1",
"_source:
    {
        {
            "user":"xyz",
            "message":"for increase in fields",
            "date":"2013-06-12"
        }
    }
```